# jenkins-x returns error 1 when I try to create a cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, jenkins-x

I'm following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/continuous-delivery-eks-jenkins-x/) tutorial. I'm running the jenkins-x cli on a aws ec2 instance where I installed kubenetes and jx. I get to the part where I run the command `jx create cluster eks --cluster-name=konsek-cloud --skip-installation=true --verbose` and it errors out with

```
DEBUG: eksctl is already available on your PATH at /home/ec2-user/.jx/bin/eksctl
DEBUG: aws-iam-authenticator is already available on your PATH at /home/ec2-user/.jx/bin/aws-iam-authenticator
DEBUG: Dependencies to be installed:
DEBUG: kubectl is already available on your PATH at /usr/bin/kubectl
DEBUG: helm is already available on your PATH at /home/ec2-user/.jx/bin/helm
error: exit status 1
```

I cannot figure out how to get more information out of it or figure out what is wrong. Can someone please suggest ways to "turn up" the logging output? or know something I can try to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same issue. It seems the eksctl that is being installed upon first use is not working for me. I went to the eksctl site and installed it from there (https://eksctl.io/introduction/installation/)

With the jx eksctl binary :

```
➜  ~ jx create cluster eks --cluster-name=konsek-cloud --skip-installation=true --verbose
DEBUG: eksctl is already available on your PATH at /Users/<user>/.jx/bin/eksctl
DEBUG: aws-iam-authenticator is already available on your PATH at /Users/<user>/.jx/bin/aws-iam-authenticator
DEBUG: Dependencies to be installed: 
DEBUG: kubectl is already available on your PATH at /usr/local/bin/kubectl
DEBUG: helm is already available on your PATH at /usr/local/bin/helm
DEBUG: brew is already available on your PATH at /usr/local/bin/brew
error: exit status 1
```

With the manually installed binary :

```
➜  ~ jx create cluster eks --cluster-name=konsek-cloud --skip-installation=true --verbose
DEBUG: eksctl is already available on your PATH at /usr/local/bin/eksctl
DEBUG: aws-iam-authenticator is already available on your PATH at /usr/local/bin/aws-iam-authenticator
DEBUG: Dependencies to be installed: 
DEBUG: kubectl is already available on your PATH at /usr/local/bin/kubectl
DEBUG: helm is already available on your PATH at /usr/local/bin/helm
DEBUG: brew is already available on your PATH at /usr/local/bin/brew
Creating EKS cluster - this can take a while so please be patient...
...
```